# preg_match match a defined number of characters requiring at least one digit and at least one letter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regex to extract a code_number,
the requirements are:

- It must be 5 characters long
- It must contain at least one digit in any position
- It must contain al least one letter in any position

Ideally this should be done using only one regex.

With the following regex I'm almost there, the problem is that this regex does not comply whit the third requirement, it should not match the `11111` because the lack of at least one letter

```
$regex = '~\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\d[a-zA-Z0-9]*~';
$sms = ' 11111 keyrod  07:30 02.10.2013';

preg_match($regex, $sms, $matches);

print_r($matches); // print array([0] => 11111)
```

How could I change this regex to not match a string of only number?

Comment: Based on the SMS the only thing that would match is the time string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$subject = ' :::5: abcde4 abcd4 12345 abcde :a:1:';

$regex = '~(?<= |^)(?=\S{0,4}\d)(?=\S{0,4}[a-z])\S{5}(?= |$)~i';

preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

explanation:

`(?<=)` and `(?=)` are respectively a lookbehind and a lookahead assertions. They test a condition before or after and don't eat any characters. (They are zero width)

In this case:

```
(?<= |^)  --> a space or the beginning of the string before
(?= |$)   --> a space or the end of the string after
```

The character class:

```
\S  --> all characters that are not white (space, tab, newline..)
```

The conditions:

At least one digit is forced by the lookahead:

`(?=\S{0,4}\d)` there's between 0 and 4 non-blank characters and a digit. In other words you can have:

```
1
x1
xx1
xxx1
xxxx1
```

it's the same for the letters with `(?=\S{0,4}[a-z])`

The number of characters for the string is forced with `\S{5}` and the first and final lookaround that forbid all non-white characters before and after.

Comment: Does not seems to work in prints Array
(
    [0] => 11111
    [1] => 11111
)

Comment: @Cesar: retry, you must obtain only `abcd4` and `:a:1:`

Comment: yes now it works. Would you mind to explain your regex, at least this parts `(?<= |^)` and `(?= |$)` the rest I think is equivalent to @Jonathan Kuhn answer, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Cesar: the difference is that pattern allow non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the rules you describe, nothing in your `$sms` string will match. But based on those rules, try this:

```
preg_match('~\b(?=[a-z0-9]{0,4}[a-z])(?=[a-z0-9]{0,4}[0-9])[a-z0-9]{5}\b~i', $subject, $matches);
```

Using your example string and Casimir's example string: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NA2mI5

Output:

```
//Your example string:
Array
(
)

//Other sample string:
Array
(
    [0] => abcd4
)
```

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ ???, how so? I even posted the example code running and working. As far as I can tell from the OP's rules, it does.

Comment: Nevermind. Was expecting it to match all of the items from my string, you're using preg_match, I loaded up a string expecting multiple matches. +1.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, excatly that was my problem, my regex was matching `11111` when it shouldn't